# wait for a series of methods to complete node.js

Tags: node.js

I have the following code, where the str array will be added with json objects in the fetchRows function. The issue is that, it is sending the str before fetching the value from the fetchrows. Basically i want the four methods to end before sending the array str.

```
var app = express();
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
    str = [];
    async.waterfall([connect, execute, fetchRows], done );    
    wait.launchFiber(done);
    res.send(str);
    console.log("in done" + str);
    //res.send(str);
});
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score -1):

**Note: I don't know async**

nodejs is an event driven system, nothing blocks it except written in a blocked manner. What happens in your code above is when the node engine reaches the line

```
async.waterfall([connect, execute, fetchRows], done );
```

It calls the function. It is the async module that then, ensures that connect is called and finishes before execute function and then fetchRows. But immediately node hits this line it does not block, it inserts what to do at some later time in future, and continues to the line below

```
res.send(str);
```

So, obviously this would finish first

**Easy Solution**

remember I don't know async

```
var app = express();
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
    str = [];
    async.waterfall([connect, execute, fetchRows, finish], done );    

    // I don't know what this line does
    wait.launchFiber(done);

    function finish() {
        res.send(str);
    }

});
```

What this solution simply does is to wrap your response.send(str) into a function and put as the last function to be called after fetchRows.